# SQL query design example

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a table like this (Table1) and was wanting to create a new table with a query that creates a new "ID" for each field (Table2).  How would you go about this with SQL? This is a pretty easy question I hope.

Table1:

```
SetID   Structure    Day1    Day2    Day3
1          A         10       15      20
2          B          7       12      17
```

Table2:

```
NewID    Structure   Day   Data   SetID
1            A        1     10     1
2            A        2     15     1 
3            A        3     20     1
4            B        1      7     2
5            B        2     12     2
6            B        3     17     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property of the ID field of Table 2 with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.  SQL will automatically increment as rows are added.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** - just saw the ms-access tag, this probably won't work in Access. I'll leave this here just in case it helps at all though

Try something like this - using ROW_NUMBER to get the newID and UNPIVOT to change your columns into rows. If you want to change the string value Day1/2/3 that'd be a small change, but for now, I've just taken the column names as is

```
declare @tbl table (SetID INT NOT NULL, Structure VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, Day1 INT NOT NULL, Day2 INT NOT NULL, Day3 INT NOT NULL);

insert into @tbl VALUES (1, 'A', 10, 15, 20), (2, 'B', 7, 12, 17);

select * From @tbl

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY up.Structure, up.[Day]) AS [NewID], 
    up.Structure, up.[Day], up.Data, up.SetID
FROM @tbl t
UNPIVOT (
    Data
    FOR [Day] IN (Day1, Day2, Day3)
) up
```